# Does an infinite Union of balls with centre 1/n and radius 1/(2^n ) have volume in R?

Tags: analysis

This question asks whether a union (from n=1 to infinity) of an open ball with centre 1/n and radius 1/(2^n) has volume in R. I believe it does, but I'm not sure how to go about proving it.

Comment: Apart from some overlapping between balls for small $n$ (up to $n=6$), the volume is just the sum of the individual disjoint ball volumes ...

Comment: not sure what "has volume" means. If we're talking about $\Bbb R$, you probably mean length. If $\Bbb R^2$, then area. If $\Bbb R^3$, then yes, it does have volume. It has at least volume given by the first ball.

Comment: Usually "has volume" means "is Jordan measurable" (hence why the wording isn't really dimension dependent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, if the question is: Has the union a measure greater than zero and smaller than infinitiy? Lets denote $U_n=(1/n-1/2^n,1/n+1/2^n)$, then for the usual Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ you have $\lambda(U_n)=1/2^{n}*2=1/2^{n-1}$. All in all you have:

\begin{eqnarray} 1&=&\lambda(U_1)\leq\lambda\left(\cup U_n\right)\leq\sum \lambda(U_n)\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=2.
\end{eqnarray}
The second inequality is because, as Hegen von Eitzen pointed out, there are some overlappings of your intervalls.